# How to get all Type<T>s where T is many different types?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following `Types`:

```
IMyType,
IMyType<MyClass1>,
IMyType<MyClass2>,
IMyType<string>
```

Using reflection such as this:

```
typeof(MyCurrentClass).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("IMyType")).ToArray()
```

I can get an array of `Types`, but it will only contain `IMyType` and `IMyType<>`.

Can I get specific types such as `IMyType<MyClass1>` using reflection?

Comment: do you mean all types that implements `IMyType<MyClass1> `? question is not clear.

Comment: What are you going to _do_ with that type?  Create an instance?  You could create an `IMyType` with just about any generic parameter.

Comment: IMyType can be any generic parameter, I'd like to scan Assemblies to see which ones are being used(like IMyType<int>)

Comment: The "I" prefix usually indicates an interface. Can you provide an example class declaration you would like to find using reflection?

Comment: @RJP for what purpose?  There's not a built-in way to see what instances of a generic class are used (it's not in the metadata of the assembly like the generic type itself), so there may be a different way of solving whatever problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse IL to truly get all usages. However, if you are content with just finding types and methods that use `IMyType` or `IMyType<>`, you can use reflection to enumerate through all types in all loaded assemblies and look to see if the type in question derives from `IMyType` or `IMyType<>` using `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`. Then, enumerate through each method or property in the type and ask if the types of any of the parameters or the return type derive from `IMyType` or `IMyType<>`, using the same mechanism. That's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

`IMyType<MyClass1>` is not part of your assembly and that's why `GetTypes` doesn't return it. What your assembly contains is `IMyType<>` generic definition that let's you create `IMyType<T>` where `T` is anything (you can do that either from your code, or at runtime using reflection). It doesn't mean new type will be created for even one of them - the generic definition will be used for them.

I don't think there is a way to check what `IMyType<T>` concrete instances were created at any given time in program execution.

You could try using static code analysis tools to scan your codebase and see what it being used as generic parameter for given generic type, but I don't know what tools have that feature.